# issue with pacemaker ipaddr2 and IPsrcaddr

Tags: cluster, ip-address, pacemaker

I'm having trouble with setting up a cluster which contains two nodes.
I want to setup a cluster with two centos nodes with a floating ip address and all packet which sends out from my active cluster node be from Virtual_IP not from the IP that is registered directly onto the NIC.

For this purpose I create two resource ocf_heartbeat_IPaddr2 and ocf:heartbeat:IPsrcaddr with these commands.

```
pcs resource create virtual_ip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=192.168.100.10 cidr_netmask=24 op monitor interval=30s
```

and

```
pcs resource create src_ip ocf:heartbeat:IPsrcaddr ipaddress=192.168.100.10 cidr_netmask=24 op monitor interval=30
```

then I create a group of two resources for ordering resource and create a constraint.

```
pcs resource  group add IPS virtual_ip  src_ip

pcs constraint order set virtual_ip  src_ip
```

but my src_ip resource is stopped. I want to all incoming packet and outgoing packet from my cluster be from virtual ip.  IPaddr2 resource is started and fine but I dont know why IPsrcaddr is stopped ?

Answer (score 0):

it's probably a bug in NetworkManager .
first restart NetworkManager service if it dosent resolve issue you probably should config your nic with network script in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<nic name>` and disable NetworkManager.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).